# Architectural Issue in ASP.Net application with Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, architecture, asp.net-web-api

We have an 3 layer architecture of ASP.Net application which builds with SQL back end and running in Production for last 2 years.

Now we plan to start develop Version 2 of that application by expose data through Web-API. So, we are busy creating the POC for that architectural implementation.

Problem is, we have an existing solution with 3 projects(ASP.NET+BAL+DAL). So, I planned to replace DAL with Web-API because it itself contains Models to interact with back end Database.
I have created a separate solution for Web-API. In my POC, Web-API runs in separate port`(ex:localhost:122)` & My ASP.NET application runs in  with default port`(ex:localhost:80)`. From my ASP.NET application, while I call the Web-API controllers its not returning results. But while checking the Web-API like `"http://localhost:122/api/Products"` i'm getting the responses.

While seeing the sample Architectures from google, People introduce "Service Layer" in the main(ASP.NET+BAL+ServiceLayer) solution and keep calling that service layer will internally call the original(withich connects with DB) Web-API. Is that only way of doing it ?

Please correct me if my assumptions are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exposing a Web API, it is best to think of it like an alternate UI.  It just so happens that it is a very ugly UI (proabably JSON or XML).  And it isn't very usable by average users because they would have to construct requests by hand etc.

A 3 Tier architecture is about preserving the BAL and DAL for multiple front ends.  Web API is an alternate front end.  So, it would seem best to reference BAL and DAL inside a new process (the Web API) and then expose it.

I'm not sure if this is the same concept as a "Service Layer" or not.  That term is overloaded with many different meanings to different people.

So, I would not replace the DAL with the Web API (because it has models etc).  Instead, use the Web API models (or view models) to define the alternate front end structure and map to these from existing BAL services and entities.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I can do add reference of BAL, DAL in my Web-API. But my problem is, why can't I consume data from Web-API (which runs in different port) directly in my ASP.NET application.

Comment: Are these calls being made from Javascript in the ASP.NET application. Or server-side?

Comment: @KarthickJ. Because DAL interfaces are too fine grained, they are too chatty for HTTP and they need support for transactions.  HTTP just isn't optimized for that style of interactions.

Comment: @DavinTryon -  Exactly !! I'm doing Ajax call to fill my JQGrid.

Comment: You are probably hitting an issue with CORS.

Comment: How to solve that !! I'm not sure about that :-( when i google i found the same CORS over all the links. :-P

Comment: You are making a cross-origin request if you are requesting a different port.  This should help: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: This is what i want. I'll let you know once i done with that. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Still I'm getting this error in my chrome."XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:2020/api/Person/GetPersons?_search=false&nd=1391178927161&rows=-1&page=1&sidx=strID&sord=desc. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5050' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: You need to add a header to the server.

Comment: In "localhost:2020" i have my Web Api running. In "localhost:5050" my ASP.NET application is running

Comment: In my WebApiConfig, if i gave var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors); Every thing works fine. But if i give  var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://127.0.0.1:5050", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors); It doesn't seems to work

Comment: @DavinTryon - Header ? you mean "[EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com", 
    headers: "accept,content-type,origin,x-my-header", methods: "*")]"

Comment: There error message says: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".  So, it is not finding the header from the server.  I'm not a CORS expert, so I don't think I'll be of much help from here.  Here are some links to check out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx  and: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/21/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis-take-2.aspx